# Is DistributedPubSub mediator stashing the messages for unreachable members of the cluster

Tags: akka, akka-cluster, akka-remote-actor

In a clustered environment, we are sending the message through DistributedPubSub mediator. So, we've some machines which are unreachable in the cluster, when the message was sent. And these machines comes reachable again before the "autodowning" has expired, then these machines do get the messages.

Does this mean that DistributedPubSub mediator stashes the messages for the unreachable members of the cluster and delivers them when they become reachable again?

Answer (score 0):

Our scenario for the above mentioned query was -

1. Cluster environment consisting e.g. 3 servers on 3 different machines
2. During communication, one of the server was made unreachable (server process was paused) and then the message replay was simulated.

So in above case, we had connectivity, so packet was reaching the machine. Since process was paused and packet was not lost, the server process was getting message once it was resumed.

So to simulate the desired scenario in correct manner, instead of pausing the process, we disconnected one of the machine from the network, so that the other members of the cluster were unreachable to the disconnected member.

**So the conclusion is that, there is no stashing of the messages by DistributedPubSubMediator in akka-cluster.**